# Formatting date from mm/dd/yyyy to MM DD, YYYY

Tags: java, date, format

For example it will format the date 2/15/2014 to February 15, 2014

I have tried a switch to get the month and that works out, but I cant figure out how to get the rest after.

This is what I have so far :

```
private void formatDate()
{
    String month = dateDeparture.substring(0, dateDeparture.indexOf('/'));
    switch(dateDeparture)
    {
    case 1:
        month = "January";
        break;
    case 2:
        month = "February";
        break;
    case 3:
        month = "March";
        break;
    case 4:
        month = "April";
        break;
    case 5:
        month = "May";
        break;
    case 6:
        month = "June";
        break;
    case 7:
        month = "July";
        break;
    case 8:
        month = "August";
        break;
    case 9:
        month = "September";
        break;
    case 10:
        month = "October";
        break;
    case 11:
        month = "November";
        break;
    default:
        month = "December";
        break;  
    }
    dateDeparture = month+" "+dateDeparture.substring(dateDeparture.indexOf('/'),  dateDeparture.lastIndexOf('/'))+ dateDeparture.substring(dateDeparture.lastIndexOf('/'));

}
```

Comment: Are you able to use `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat` or must you do it by hand?

Comment: I can use anything, I don't know how to use those formatters though.

Comment: Don't even think about not using `SimpleDateFormat` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a class called SimpleDateFormat. Use that to achieve what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use a date formatting class like SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat numericDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = numericDateFormatter.parse(dateDeparture);
SimpleDateFormat mixedDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM d, yyyy");
String dateNew = mixedDateFormatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are using Java 7, you can use `String` in `switch` statements...

But, there are two problems with your current code...

One, you are using `dateDeparture` and not `month`

```
switch(dateDeparture)
```

And your case statements are using `int` instead of `String`

```
case 1:
```

Instead, you need to use something more like...

```
switch (month) {
    case "1":
    case "01":
        month = "January";
        break;
}
```

Now, because you month "might" be zero indexed, you need to take into account both occurrences...

If you're using Java 6 or eailer, you will need to convert the `String` value to an `int`...

```
int monthValue = Integer.parseInt(month);
switch (monthValue) {
    case 1:
        //...
```

A simpler approach would be to use the inbuilt APIs available to you...

Start by converting the `String` value to a `Date` value...

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = in.parse(dateDeparture);
```

Then format the date...

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
String value = out.format(date);
```

Take a close look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
//splits string based on / delimiter 
String[] MDY = dateDeparture.split("/");
int month = Integer.parseInt(MDY[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(MDY[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(MDY[2]);
```

then use your switch statement on *month* and format *day* and *year* to your liking.